# Weird antialias artefacting with react native on nested posed components

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation, styled-components, popmotion

I am creating a component that animates a group of buttons in an elastic staggered way using `react-native-pose`. The buttons them selves use *pose* to animate the pressed state. I have almost got it looking how I want it although I'm not sure I'm doing things correctly.

This is what I want to achhieve...
[image]

... However the text looks awful like its got jpg artefacts on it :

[image]

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import posed from 'react-native-pose';
import Button from './src/components/Button';

const ScreenContainer = styled.View({
  flex: 1,
  padding: 20,
  marginTop: 100
});

const Buttons = posed.View({
  visible: {
    staggerChildren: 100
  },
  hidden: {
    staggerChildren: 100
  }
});

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    buttonPose: 'hidden'
  };

  items = [
    { id: 0, label: 'One' },
    { id: 1, label: 'Two' },
    { id: 2, label: 'Three' }
  ];

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({
      buttonPose: 'visible'
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ScreenContainer>
        <Buttons pose={this.state.buttonPose}>
          {this.items.map(item => (
            <Button label={item.label} key={item.id} />
          ))}
        </Buttons>
      </ScreenContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

**Button.js**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import posed from 'react-native-pose';

const Container = styled(
  posed.View({
    visible: {
      opacity: 1,
      x: 0
    },
    hidden: {
      opacity: 0,
      x: -100
    }
  })
)({
  marginBottom: 20
});

const Background = styled(
  posed.View({
    // If I comment out these poses the problem goes away
    pressIn: {
      scale: 1.1
    },
    pressOut: {
      scale: 1
    }
  })
)({
  padding: 20,
  backgroundColor: '#f9415d',
  borderRadius: 10
});

const Label = styled.Text({
  fontSize: 18,
  color: 'white',
  textAlign: 'center'
});

export default class Button extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    buttonPose: 'pressOut'
  };

  onPressIn = () => {
    this.setState({
      buttonPose: 'pressIn'
    });
  };

  onPressOut = () => {
    this.setState({
      buttonPose: 'pressOut'
    });
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {};

  render() {
    const { onPressIn, onPressOut } = this;
    const { buttonPose } = this.state;
    const { label } = this.props;
    return (
      <Container>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPressIn={onPressIn} onPressOut={onPressOut}>
          <Background pose={buttonPose} withParent={false}>
            <Label>{label}</Label>
          </Background>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone offer any insight into why the text and also the rounded corners look so artifacted and low res?

Comment: Are you completely dependent on this library or are you open to just using your own css so you can apply properties like `backface-visibility`, `font-smoothing` and force hardware acceleration?

Comment: @ChrisW. I am using React Native for mobile development. This does not have CSS.